# NoMethodError: undefined method `call'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

When running the following test suite:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  before { @user = User.(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com" }

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
end
```

I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: before { @user = User.(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com") }
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `call' for #<Class:0x007fdfd5dd8008>
  # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Creating the user works in the console just fine and it responds to the methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a syntax error:

```
before { @user = User.(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com" }
```

There should be no `.` between `User` and the opening parenthesis. Also you are missing the closing parenthesis. Try:

```
before { @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com") }
```

If you wonder about the specific error message, in newer Ruby versions `.()` works like `call`:

```
l = lambda { |x| x * x }
#=> #<Proc:0x007fe5d3907188@(pry):39 (lambda)>
l.call(3)
#=> 9
l.(3)
#=> 9
```