# Angular2 Rails Backend Post from json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json, angular

The way I understand it is if you specify the correct content headers, than Rails will automatically build the params hash in the format it expects.  However, my params hash has some... well... issues.  Here's some info

Angular 2 http request

```
onSubmit(values:any) : void {

  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/people/",JSON.stringify(values),{ headers: headers })
    .subscribe((res: Response) => {
      this.data = res.json();
      this.loading = true;
  });
}
```

Rails picks up the request but incorrectly formats the request data.  Here is my rails create method.

```
def create
  @person = Person.new.(params[:person])

  puts params[:person] # writes to Console

  if @person.save
     render json: @person
  end
end
```

Here's info from rails debugger from my `puts` statement

```
Parameters: {"name"=>"Christopher", "age"=>"37", "person"=>{"name"=>"Christopher", "age"=>"37"}}
```

and the remaining error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `call' for #<Person:0x007fec515761c0>):
app/controllers/people_controller.rb:16:in `create'
```

What am I doing wrong other than programming on a Saturday night?

Comment: I'm not familiriazed with Ruby, but this is not an angular2 issue. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024908/nomethoderror-undefined-method-call).

Answer (score 3):

I think this

```
@person = Person.new.(params[:person])
```

shouldn't have that extra `.` and instead be

```
@person = Person.new(params[:person])
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than the typo that Miles mentioned above, the major problem ended up being that I was using strong parameters the wrong way.

I did this:

```
@person = Person.new(params[:person])
```

Instead of this:

```
@person = Person.new(person_params)
```